# streaming channels with iphone?

Tags: iphone, streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

can someone help me in how to use MPMoviePlayerController for streaming channels. 
  My code works well with the Apple [links](http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8). Now how can I make it for streaming live tv channels. Thanks

Comment: who made it down vote!! I just found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue partly. The solution is:
Make sure you are member of Apple developer program. Login into your apple account and download
MakeRefMovie software from [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?=http%20#). Put it on your server. It will open any streaming channel just by giving the link of the channel and it will create .mov file. Access the .mov  files from any Apple device and present it through MPMoviePlayerController. Set the URL of MPMoviePlayerController to .mov file on your server. It will work!!